# Tags como [git-commit], [git-branch] e etc, são realmente necessárias quando já temos a tag [git]?

Tags: debate, tags

Penso eu que deveríamos remover quase todas tags prefixadas sobre `git-`, afinal, creio eu que o programa `git` tem uma série de comandos e a tag [git](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) já cobrem o assunto, as tags são:

- <s>[git-push](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-push)</s>
- <s>[git-branch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-branch)</s>
- <s>[git-commit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commit)</s>
- <s>[histórico-git](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hist%c3%b3rico-git)</s>
- [branch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/branch)
- [commit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commit)

> Até o momento não encontrei mais nenhuma relacionada

Concorda que todas são dispensáveis, ou alguma delas é necessária? Por favor comente

Comment: Estou a olhar aqui o uso dessas tags, começando por [tag:git-branch]. Com exceção de [uma pergunta nada a ver com o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195915/64969), ainda não encontrei nenhum uso dessa tag independente da tag [tag:git]

Comment: Pronto, terminei a análise pelo menos de [tag:git-branch], ela não existe sozinha numa coisa que faça sentido

Comment: Para mim a tag **git** já basta. Os comandos são parte do problema ou contexto da pergunta.

Comment: Talvez a tag [tag:branch] tenha um sentido mais diferenciado do que **git**, mas eu particularmente não creio que ela deva existir, talvez ela esteja dentro de gerenciamento de projeto ou sei lá. E a tag [tag:commit] é enganosa, pois pode ser commit de VCS como de banco de dados

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Realmente tags sobre comandos específicos do git são redundantes, principalmente porque não há volume perguntas vinculadas a elas (se houvesse volume faria sentido categorizar).  Sendo assim, eu as mesclei com a tag [git](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git).

Sobra outras tags, acredito que há casos em que elas poderiam fazer sentido.

## Branches

[branch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/branch), por exemplo, poderia se referir à estratégia de uso de DCVSs em geral por meio de ADGs. Em teoria claro, na prática é mais comum que as perguntas sejam feitas num contexto de GIT ou SVN. E ainda o termo mais correto, como estratégia, seria *branching*. Em gerenciamento de projetos, o termo é *gerenciamento de configuração*. O primeiro não é intuitivo para brasileiros e o segundo é feio e chato (dá até aversão e lembra aqueles gerentes de projetos que não entendem nada de programação e querem dar pitaco em como organizar o código).

Além do mais, [existe uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120867/sugest%C3%A3o-de-como-gerenciar-projeto-com-diversas-varia%C3%A7%C3%B5es) que parece fazer bom uso da tag. E outras perguntas que usam a tag com SVN, o que também poderia ser útil se eu quisesse saber sobre estratégias de *branching* em diversos CVSs.

Enfim, por falta de um padrão melhor que seja intuitivo e prático, não fiz alteração em tal tag.

## Commits

Já a tag [commit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commit) é um caso bem mais complicado. A documentação da tag diz que ela se refere ao GIT, o que não é bem exato porque praticamente todos os CVSs possuem tal conceito. Em cima disto, há vários casos de uso com tags de banco de dados, fazendo o uso desta tag bastante confuso tanto para quem quer pesquisar quanto para quem quer perguntar.

Para resolver este problema teríamos que:

- Primeiro, estabelecer um padrão de tags para os casos em que o conceito de commit aparece tanto para bancos de dados quanto para CVSs.
- Segundo, revisar todas as questões e aplicar o ajuste.

Creio que outro tópico no meta para discutir o assunto seria necessário. Fiquem à vontade para criá-lo.

Comment: Eu concordo plenamente sobre o branch e commit, só precisamos revisar a commit pelo motivo que você citou. Afinal existem outros sistemas semelhantes ao Git e talvez usos "diferentes", mas ainda proveitosos. PS: as demais tags eu já matei, as outras duas eu não mexi. Obrigado!