# As tags [select] e [where] deveriam ser [sql-select] e [sql-where]?

Tags: debate, tags

As tags [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) e [where](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/where) (e demais relacionadas a linguagem SQL) estão sem prefixo. Uma tag parecida e com prefixo é a [sql-update](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-update).

As tags [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) e [where](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/where) deveriam ser [sql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select) e [sql-where](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-where)?

**EDIÇÃO:** acabei de ver que de fato a tag [sql-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select) existe. Ela tem a mesma recomendação de uso da [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select).

Comment: Faz sentido pulverizar as tags de SQL? Se sim, eu me mostra a favor de mudar os nomes de [tag:select] e [tag:where].

Comment: Somente a tag [tag:sql] já não é suficiente? Não é este um caso semelhante ao das tags [tag:href], [tag:onclick] e [tag:data], as quais [tag:html] e [tag:html5] já cobriam perfeitamente?

Comment: o `sql-select` é direcionadas a busca com filtro com banco sql, mas acho q deveria ter uma tag `select` porém direcionada a buscas com filtro em bancos no-sql como o firebase

Comment: Como assim banco SQL? O ruim de select é que pode ser a da linguagem SQL, pode ser específico de um SGBD, pode ser a tag HTML, pode ser a função .NET e outra infinidade de coisas. A questão é: quando algo precisa mesmo de uma tag específica? Será que nesse seu caso a tag nosql já não bastaria? Ou a tag mongodb, cassandra, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Creio eu que o caso é semelhante a este [Tags como [git-commit], [git-branch] e etc, são realmente necessárias quando já temos a tag [git]?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6436/3635)

A tag [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) é um comando da sintaxe SQL (seja mysql, sqlite, oracle, etc), logo é uma tag que deveria morrer, pois as tags dos SGBDs especifico já são mais que suficiente

O mesmo vale para [where](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/where), tem em mysql e oracle (não lembro se existe em outros bancos), então as tags dos SGBDs que suportam são mais que suficiente.

Não precisamos de tag pra cada "coisinha", só se for algo muito especifico mesmo, mas nessas perguntas podem notar que a tag sendo [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select), [update](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/update), [where](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/where), [insert](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/insert) e etc, geralmente são erros de sintaxe ou são coisas que não faz necessidade falar, pois o problema as vezes é resolvido com JOIN (depende da pergunta), ou as vezes a pessoa sugere separar em duas queries diferentes, então no geral todas essas sub-tags muitas vezes acabam por se inúteis

### Exceções

Talvez uma tag para `VIEW` faça sentido, pois isso sim seria um assunto especifico

> Talvez eu edite para adicionar mais possiveis sub-tags, qualquer sugestão comentem

Comment: Concordo 100%. Sempre que eu encontrar uma pergunta com tags de comandos vou alterar para a tag [tag:sql] daqui pra frente.

Comment: @Renan acho que muitas vezes [tag:sql] é dispensável (redundante), se tiver a tag do sgdb especifico acho que é o suficiente, mas adicionar sql não faz mal algum, o problema desta tag é que o pessoal confunde com mysql.